# Resize pdf files but with different for width and height

Tags: pdf

I need to resize a pdf (to remove the margins). It's not an image in pdf, it's a book. But, of course, the upper/lower margins are thinner than the left/right ones. So I was wondering whether there was a way, in ubuntu, to resize a pdf but with different resizing factors for horizontal and vertical resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used it myself, but maybe [pdfcrop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/pdfcrop.1.html) can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape, available in the repositories, can edit PDF files. Probably depends somewhat on the contents of your PDF as to whether or not you will be happy with the output, but that would be my first option.

Comment: it's for a scan of an old book, so I need a solution that does it 200 pages at a time...

Comment: Oh, then Inkscape is probably not a good solution... Maybe PDFtk? http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/ or something from this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software . I would look for something that works from the command line and then create bash script to do the job...